# while running query on hive external table from trino, getting error Malformed ORC file. Cannot read SQL type 'double' from ORC stream of type STRING

Tags: presto, trino

> while running query on hive table from trino , getting below error

> SQL Error [16777219]: Query failed (#20220820_042537_00480_dszgc): Error opening Hive split hdfs://CDPSAPRODHA/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/customer_360.db/transaction_lines/order_date=20220818/part-00167-c28380bb-d942-445e-acd6-09ec8b29d777.c000 (offset=0, length=213919): Malformed ORC file. Cannot read SQL type 'double' from ORC stream '.assortment_id' of type STRING with attributes {} [hdfs://CDPSAPRODHA/warehouse/tablespace/external/hive/customer_360.db/transaction_lines/order_date=20220818/part-00167-c28380bb-d942-445e-acd6-09ec8b29d777.c000]

> data type of "assortment_id" is string

```
Query :
select * from transaction_lines;
```

Comment: The table definition has column defined as double where as on the actual file it is of STRING type. Try changing the table definition matching ORC.